# Excel sheet pops up asking for Password, even after it is hard coded in VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, passwords

I'm trying to access an Excel file from a network. This file is password-protected and it is hard-coded in the program:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\179.29.27.153\xyz Sample\High Risk Alert.xlsx", Password:="x1y3z2")
```

On testing it works fine in my PC. However, on running, it pops up asking to enter the password, in the client PC.

[image]

Comment: Have you trusted the micros on client PC? Check the settings on Trust Center.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AadityaDengle, it worked super fine!